# How to find element in <a href> (not have id, class)

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to get questioner list in [website](https://9nice.site/dwqa-questions/). This element not have id, class. I tried to use XPATH for find it but I only get 1 same result.
This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://9nice.site")
link1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/nav[1]/ul/li/a")
link1.click()
link2 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dwqa-question-item")
sleep(2)
for x in link2:
    who_asked_question = x.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/a").text
    print(who_asked_question)
sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

This is result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following. Check if this satisfies your requirements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://9nice.site")

link1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/nav[1]/ul/li/a")
link1.click()
link2 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='dwqa-question-item']")
time.sleep(2)

for iteration, item in enumerate(link2):
        iteration += 1
        question = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='dwqa-question-item'][{iteration}]")
        who_asked_question = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='dwqa-question-item'][{iteration}]/div[@class='dwqa-question-meta']/span/a")
        print(who_asked_question.text)
time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

Output:

```
Linh Nhi
Qúy
kuj9xst3
kuj9xst3
kuj9xst3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me an explanation please?

Comment: Your method `find_elements_by_class_name` was not working correctly. Also, the loop was not iterating correctly on items. I have used `x-path` for obtaining the author name and the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start